# Maven Release Plugin together with cifriendly versions

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am just setting up a Maven multi-module project with `${revision}` as version as described in https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

The property `${revision}` is set in the parent POM and used as version number throughout all modules.

This works fine for SNAPSHOT builds, but when I run the Maven release plugin, the version gets replaced by something like `1.0.0` and then `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. So the cifriendly versions are gone after one release.

Is there a way to configure the Maven release plugin in a way that cifriendly versions are not destroyed?

Comment: Can you explain the reason for using maven-release-plugin together with ci friendly?

Comment: What would you recommend instead? We used Maven release plugin up to now to release all our projects. Now we are starting to use multi-module projects and I thought that having the version in one place (as `${revision}`) is better than having the version in each and every module. Of course, one can use `versions:set` to set the versions for all modules, but I thought using `${revision}` is the more modern and nicer way.

Comment: @khmarbaise On the other hand, of course, we could give up using maven-release-plugin, but this means that we need to craft the necessary steps ourselves.

Comment: If you like to use `versions:set` does not really make sense in relationship with maven-release-plugin cause this can be configured either automatically (increment last digit) or explicit via parameter. CI friendly is more intended to be used standalone without release plugin like just setting a version from outside (for example via CI tool)...but of course it would make sense to handle the usage in maven-release-plugin as well (currently not the case)...

Comment: So should I _not_ use the `${revision}` in my version in the multi-module project? At least until the maven release plugin can handle it? For `versions:set`: It did not mean that for the release itself, but when I want to update the version of the project locally. This is easier with `${revision}` because the property is just set in one place.

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok, I decided to remove the `${revision}` from my POMs until https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-935 is resolved.

Comment: The concept of the release plugin is fundamentally at odds with CI-friendly versioning. You're asking the equivalent of how to make a relational database (ACID) act like a No-SQL (BASE) database. How can I make a gas-powered car work like a bicycle? These are fundamentally different approaches.

Comment: @ingyhere I understand that the release plugin may be not the best choice to build releases on a modern CI system. Nevertheless, when you choose to use the release plugin, using `${revision}` would be useful to avoid the repetition of the version number in each and every module.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I think you may have been looking for `${project.version}' which is available irrespective of CI Friendly version tooling.

Comment: @ingyhere Thanks, but no.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CI Friendly version scheme is intended to replace the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/), *not* complement it. In today's development world most teams are relying on CI servers for integration testing, performing automated tests and either releasing with continuous delivery or continuous deployment. *The concept of a `SNAPSHOT` is truly limited when everything is potentially a `SNAPSHOT`.*

[Notably, the Release Plugin executes 4 to 5 times more processes than a properly implemented CI Friendly configuration.](https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html) Imagine a 50-minute build using the release plugin becoming a 15-minute build using the CI strategy. [Now that's modernization!](https://www.socallinuxexpo.org/sites/default/files/presentations/SCaLE-18x-Maven_Renewed_u2.pdf)

The basic idea is that values used in versions will be collected from the [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) (`Git`, `SVN`, etc.) and the [CIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (`Jenkins`, `Travis CI`, `GitLab`, etc.) at build time and used to modify or set the POM/release version. These values are things like the build number, the shortened Git hash or anything else.

**Procedure to implement CI Friendly Maven builds:**

- Maven [supports only a handful of properties](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) in the `<version>` tag. These are `${revision}`, `${changelist}` and `${sha1}`.
- You can either use a hardcoded value and the acceptable properties or just something like `${revision}`. **NOTE:** I now recommend `${revision}`.
- In the `<properties>`, set values to acceptable defaults -- fake values that become clear they are from non-build machines, like `0` for the build number.
- In the `<properties>`, assemble the value for `<revision>`, e.g. the version, from other properties and hardcoded values. For instance, `<revision>1.0.0b${changelist}-${sha1}</revision>`.
- At build time, use `-D` flags to set the actual values. For instance, the `${BUILD_NUMBER}` value is injected to every Jenkins build -- `-Dchangelist=${BUILD_NUMBER}`.
- You now have the flexibility to change the version number components.

In the CI pipelines you can now detect the commit branch and perform releases from `master` by clearing all or some of these values. For instance, feature branches can calculate and add the Git hash. The semantic version is set above -- Developers now own and control it. They must know their code to make changes, and they have the freedom to increment the semantic version. It's a lot of valuable flexibility.

The sound reasoning here, though, is to speed up things and get rid of a heavyweight process that really adds little to no relevant information that ties code to its precise origin. By using CI Friendly versions you will let deployers, testers and sysadmins see the compile number and code commit hash that allows the problem to be precisely correlated to an actual code release.

It should be noted that this requires a bit of philosophical flexibility to accept a paradigm shift. Change is good, and ditching the release plugin will make your release pipelines better.

Comment: Note that if this strategy is used in a multi-module project, using dependencies from any earlier built modules should use `${project.version}` in the `<version>` tag, not `${revision}`. The reference to the project parent or module version should use `${revision}`.

Comment: Very nice answer. Much clearer than the docs. Thanks.